# Is Fourier transform has support in given interval?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Given an finite interval $(a,b)$, what is the guarantee for existence of a $L_2$ function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that whose $L_2$ Fourier transform has support in $(a,b)$?

Comment: Try to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of something very simple like a hat function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be the inverse Fourier function of the characteristic function of $[a,b]$:
$$
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\int_a^be^{-ix\xi}\,d\xi=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\frac{e^{-ibx}-e^{-iax}}{x}.
$$
$\phi$ is in $L^p$for all $p>1$, and is an example. You can construct more as follows: for any $f\in L^1\cap L^2$, $\phi\ast f$ is in $L^2$ and $\widehat{\phi\ast f}=\hat\phi\,\hat f$ has support in $[a,b]$.